# What meta-data does iCloud drive save and restore for each file or directory?

Tags: icloud, filesystem

**Observation**: Machine A had HPFS+ with iCloud drive subscription. Machine B had APFS and joined the same iCloud drive. When the content was downloaded, all the directories had a fresh modification date on them.

**Experiment / Observation 2**: Machines A and B are using the same iCloud drive. Disconnect the network connection on B. Create and empty directory on A. After some time connect B back to the network. The empty directory gets downloaded on B but with a fresh modification time (time of download on B). This does not happen for files.

**Setup**: In the above "experiments / observations", machine A is running macOS 10.12.6 on an HPFS+ (case-sensitive and encrypted). Machine B is running macOS 10.13 beta on an APFS (case-sensitive and encrypted).

**Question**: I would like to know what metadata are saved and restored for files in iCloud drive. For example what kind of time stamps are kept (creation time, last read time, last modification time, ...)? Are file names case-sensitive? Are they normalised?

Has Apple published any reference on this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html might give some clues (I didn't dig in very deep though)

Comment: Only Apple knows, and unless they publish it on the developer site, there is no official data on that.

Comment: mdls <filename> on two Macs shows all metadata the same except for those related to file opening or using (e.g. kMDItemUsedCount)

Comment: Your observation doesn't actually relate directly to your question.  I'm not saying it's not a good question.  But, when your computer downloads content from iCloud, the creation date /is/ today, because the folder structure is created, on your computer, now.  That's separate and different from file creation/modification metadata that gets downloaded.

Comment: Harv, I don't believe that to be correct - see my comment to the answer below regarding folders.  The iCloud sync propagates the same kMDItemContentCreationDate for folders and this is what is shown by get info.

Comment: I have exactly the scenario in the 'observation'.  My Machine B has same folder creation dates as Machine A, going back to 2011.

Comment: @Gilby That is interesting. I repeated the "experiment" and got the same result as before (different from your experience). I have two Macs using the same iCloud drive. One is running macOS 10.12.6 (machien A above), the other 10.13 beta (machine B above). I disconnected the network on machine B. Created a folder on the desktop of machine A (which is on iCloud drive). Connected the network on machine B two minutes later. The creation date on machine B is two minutes later. This happens only with directories (folders), not with files as far as I can see.

Comment: @Harv Thanks for your comment but I don't share the same view. Firstly this happens only with directories (folders) and not files. Secondly I would expect multiple copies of my drive on different machines to be mirror of each other. If create or modify a file or directory at time t on one machine, the same time should show up on another machine. If it is going to work based on when it is downloaded on the other machine, then things can get messy: if a machine has been out of reach from any network, then all the creation modification dates are going to be at the time it connects to a network.

Comment: @Harv The relevance of the observation to the question is that, the question is asking about the meta-data that are saved and **restored**. For folders it seems that the creation time is either not stored on iCloud servers or not restored properly.

Comment: @Loax  We are seeing different results for folders.  I have repeated the experiment exactly as you have described.  The folder on machine B (10.13 beta) gets a folder with creation date/time same as machine A, but with modify date/time being that of when it was downloaded (that is when created on machine B).

Comment: @Loax  Are we agreed that files are synchronised with all metadata intact?

Comment: @Gilby My bad an sorry, it is indeed the modification time that is different. And yes this is fine for normal files. I added the correct second "observation" to the question. I still do not see the logic behind this. A directory should have its modification date updated only when an entry in the directory is changed. iCloud  drive behaviour does not make sense in this scenario.

Comment: @Loax.  Glad we are in agreement. But I am not sure where we are to answer if your question. By experiment, metadata is preserved pretty well (open to discussion about behaviour of folder modify). But we have no reference in Apple's documentation or any other authority.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud Drive is not stored on a traditional file system per se on Apple's servers.

On your Mac, the files in iCloud Drive are stored simply on the existing file system on your hard drive - usually HFS+. You can find the files at the following path:

~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm rather interested in what metadata is stored along with each file. For example, see the "observation" I added to the question. Maybe I should change the title of the question?

Comment: If you look in the the path I referenced, you'll see that's there no extra metadata in the attributes or similar.

Comment: What information does it keep on the server-side though? For instance, from my experience (the observation mentioned in the question), it appears that the meta-data on "time created" is either not kept on the server side or is disregarded when recreating the directories in a new destination.

Comment: mdls <folder> on 2 Macs shows kMDItemContentCreationDate is the same (even though it may predate the macOS install), though kMDItemContentModificationDate is local to the specific Mac.